# Is it standard/normal to request details of illness on a return to work form (sick leave) (UK)? Should I provide the details?

Tags: united-kingdom, leave-of-absence

So, I was recently off for two days due to flu, post weekend, and I'm now returning to work. I have to complete a self assessment form, and complete an interview with my line manager. This is the policy set for all instances of sick leave regardless of length or reason.

Upon reviewing the self assessment form I was somewhat set back by the questions:

> This must be specific. For absence related to dependants or  compassionate, details of the relationship should be provided. For absence related to illness words like ‘sick’ or ‘ill’ will not suffice.

Followed by

> Did you receive medication from
>
> 1. your doctor                    Yes [    ]   No [    ]
> 2. self prescribed from chemist   Yes [    ]   No [    ]
>
>    Please give names/details of any medication being taken, prescribed
>      or
>      otherwise:

So, my question is...  Is it common practice to request such granular level of detail such as medication for basic office work (software development) sick leave, and are you at liberty to provide it?

I can't fathom what they would even do with the medication information given we don't employ pharmacists.

Update:
Posting from UK, England.

Thanks

Comment: Depending upon your location asking for such information may be illegal. Please update the question to indicate a country for better results.

Comment: @Steve Updated.

Comment: I recall these exact questions being on my self assessment form at my old company. They were brought in as the company was undergoing a take over by a much larger parent company, leading me to believe that it was part of the agreement in the take over

Comment: Somewhat off topic. I was just speaking to a colleague who was off for a short while with depression. He listed his medication. What shocked me with that is HR started giving their personal opinions on one of the medications stating "you shouldn't really be taking x as its addictive". That to me is crossing so many lines. They are not medical professionals and have absolutely no place questioning the practice of someone who is. 

It just leads me back to original question.. Given HR aren't medically qualified, for what use is listing medication?

Comment: At least in Germany, these questions are as illegal as asking for a pregnancy in the job interview. You are allowed to lie (as long as the illness does not affect your work (e.g. medicaments while using heavy machinery).

Comment: @FooTheBar While I understand what you're saying I have no reason to lie, and don't mind providing the requested information. It to me just seems brazer, moreover, after asking my coworkers they seem to think its fine without question. It can't only be me?

Comment: "and don't mind providing the requested information." Even then don't provide any information to make it easier for those who really don't want to make their illness public.

Comment: Storm forward, provide specific details, add pictures and sound snippets. Especially if you had a stomach flu. [/end sarcasm]

Comment: This seems like a gross violation of your privacy.

Comment: @Christian I did tell a white lie... My stools were unaffected, but my god did I go into great detail about their consistency. If forced to provide detail I'm going to make it stomach turning to read.

Comment: FooTheBar: The German method is perfect - being asked an illegal question any lies cannot be held against you in any way. So no reason to have a fight about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They can *ask* but you don't have to answer - as your absence was less than 7 calendar days  simply stating that you were not well enough to work is sufficient.

To quote [acas](https://www.acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=1566#returntowork):

> If a worker is absent due to sickness for seven days or less they can self-certify their absence. This means the worker informs their employer that they are not well enough to work and **do not need to provide any further medical evidence.**

(emphasis mine).

That said there *are* circumstances where the granular detail of medications you describe  is appropriate - e.g. where your role includes driving or operating Forklifts or other heavy machinery. Basic office work? Not so much - it's going to be very difficult for any employer to prove it's reasonable to know what you were/are taking, and the same goes for symptoms - they are only pertinent when it could affect your ability to perform the role or the safety of yourself or others at work. Even then it's not a right for them to *know* this information, at worst they can seek a Fit Note from the doctor.

The text of the form is likely a boiler plate one designed to cover all scenarios rather than specific to you or this employer.

Is this a hill worth dying on in this particular case? That's going to have to be your call - personally for something this trivial I would probably just answer rather than get into it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "Is this a hill worth dying on in this particular case?" No. And I'm fine providing the information. I'm just curious as to how common a practice this is, and if I'm at liberty to provide the information.

Comment: "Is this a hill worth dying on in this particular case?"  Maybe not for you. But by providing this information you make it harder for those who really do not want to make their illness public.

Answer (score 5):

A `Return to Work` procedure is standard and common place, but listing the provided medications is odd - but not illegal or unethical.

If you're on medication that can possibly affect your performance, such as pain killers, you can use this form to pre-emptively cover yourself by informing your HR department.

BUT

This information falls under [the Data Protection Act](http://www.universityhealthcentreatqueens.co.uk/website/Z00157/files/Access_to_medical_records.pdf) and is sensitive information, and should only been viewed or accessed under proper circumstances. Posting this information on an intranet site or otherwise without prior consent is in direct violation of said act.

Comment: "but not illegal or unethical" Asking for it with this pressure "This must be specific." is at least unethical and likely also illegal.

Comment: @FooTheBar no this is the standard boilerplate text used  in the UK = its the exact wording my company does I just summarise the symptoms eg vomiting, dhioreha or what have you

Comment: If you work in a restaurant, asking about vomiting or diarrhoea would be fine. If you operate heavy machines asking about dizzy spells would be fine.